# IRAPIStream COM Interface in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, rapi

I'm trying to use the OpenNETCF RAPI class to interact with a windows mobile device using the RAPI.Invoke() method.

According to the following article:
http://blog.opennetcf.com/ncowburn/2007/07/27/HOWTORetrieveTheDeviceIDFromTheDesktop.aspx

You can do the communication in either block or stream mode.  I have used block mode before, but now I need to do something a bit more complicated with a lot more data and continuous communication and therefore need to use the stream mode.  Unfortunately on that article, *and basically everywhere else*, there is no explaination of how to use IRAPIStream in .NET  I have found C/C++ documentation, but my desktop app needs to be written in C#

Does anyone know how to properly implement the IRAPIStream COM interface in .NET?
And better yet, anyone actually used RAPI.Invoke() with IRAPIStream before?  Examples would be much appreciated.

Edit: Upon a closer look at the RAPI class documentation, I realized that the Invoke() method doesn't support the stream interface.... so OpenNETCF is likely out, but maybe there is still a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that generally the most performant and stable way to push/pull large amounts of data of a device over activesync is to use a socket.
Early on we used CeRapiInvoke and a stream to pull data down of the device but ditched this early on in favour of using tcp/ip over a socket.